# Were there any "Punch A Nazi" polls done in the US?

Tags: united-states, freedom-of-speech, nazism, identity-politics

The "Punch a Nazi" event in the United States was an interesting phenomena where Richard Spencer (A self titled Identitarian) was punched by an anarchist generating the question "Is it OK to punch a Nazi?". Were there any polls done to evaluate the general attitude surrounding this issue in the US? I see many articles regarding the issue, but no polls asking people whether this action is OK or not, and not their response.

Comment: Regarding your tags, I know that the right likes to frame it that way, but I don't see how this has much to do with freedom of speech (or identity politics for that matter).

Comment: Polls can be tricky, because there is a certain amount of nuance that can't be captured. I might feel that it is illegal, and that someone should be punished for such behavior, as a matter of societal policy, while also feeling that I'd be happy to pay that price, personally.

Comment: @tim It is related to freedom of speech because unless someone is actually committing crimes against humanity the way you identify a Nazi is by what they say, write, or otherwise express.

Comment: @tim I would say that it is a freedom of speech issue, and an identity politics issue as well. After all, he was punched because of his identity, and views.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The right-wing Cato Institute did a [survey about punching Nazis](https://www.cato.org/survey-reports/state-free-speech-tolerance-america#15).

According to the survey, only 32% of the general population say that it is morally acceptable, and even among strong liberals the number is only 51%. Old white people are less likely to approve of punching Nazis than non-white or young people.

[image]

Comment: "The Cato Institute did a survey about punching Nazis" = what completely bizarre times we live in.

Comment: Polls can be tricky, because there is a certain amount of nuance that can't be captured. I might feel that it is illegal, and that someone should be punished for such behavior, as a matter of societal policy, while also feeling that I'd be happy to pay that price, personally. Good find, though. I would not have thought that this would be an issue polled.

Comment: Well, the other way of looking at that isn’t that only 51% of strong liberals think it’s fine to punch Nazis; it’s that a full fifth of conservatives, even, find it morally acceptable. That’s still half the percentage of Republicans who believe Obama might be a Muslim, but it’s pretty high.

Comment: Wow. My take from that poll is that literally half of all strong liberals think it's OK to physically assault someone based on nothing but their political ideology. For the record, it's not acceptable to physically assault anyone regardless of how reprehensible that person's beliefs are. We're supposed to be better people than the ones we wish we could punch.

Comment: For the sake of that poll, is there a definition of "Nazi"? Because if it's someone from the 1940's who's a party member, I wouldn't suggest punching them.